# Issues connecting puppet agent to master

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent, puppet-foreman

Trying to build an infrastructure based on the most recent puppet/agents available for testing purposes.

So I've been trying to run puppet agent on a node, and I'm currently getting the errors bellow, puppet master currently running on a fresh install of Foreman 1.24(EC2 Instance) and seems to be running the agent fine with no issues, different story on the agents.

I am able to reach and sign the certificates from the nodes(agents) on the master but nothing else after apart from getting the errors.

```
root@puppetagent02:~# puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get issuer certificate): [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.com]
root@puppetagent02:~#
```

Comment: So it seems that there is no puppet 6 agent for Debian 10(Buster), I was running its latest agent 5.10 which seems to handle the certificates differently from Agent 6.12, spin up a quick Centos 7 VM with the agent and got it working with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So managed to sort it out by just simply downgrading to “stretch” that has the latest package of the puppet agent, working now with no issues.